# Flutter firestore document get on iOs in release causing crash

Tags: ios, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

in my flutter (Android-Ios app) i'm facing a strange issue on this simple line of code:

```
DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> ds = await Methods().getFirestoreApp().collection('contacts').doc(docId).get();
```

This line of code works every time but fails only in one case:

- Android - debug - Virtual deivces -> **OK**
- Android - debug - Phisical deivces -> **OK**
- Android - release - Virtual deivces -> **OK**
- Android - release - Phisical deivces -> **OK**
- Ios - debug - Virtual deivces -> **OK**
- Ios - debug - Phisical deivces -> **OK**
- Ios - release - Virtual deivces -> **OK**
- Ios - release - Phisical deivces -> **OK**
- **Ios - release - On phisical iPhone 6 plus (os v 12.5.7) -> CRASH**

With crash i mean that the app closes.
No log is shown for this issue.

What i've tried:

- print logs before and after this line, the after log is not printed.
- sorround with try-catch block does not work, the app still crashes end the catch block is never called so i cannot print anything
- adding log in ...doc().onError() or in ...doc().catchError(), this are not being called like the try-catch catch block.
- Firebase crashlytics, that usually works in all other cases, does not register this crash.

I'm struggling with this issue cause i have no clue caused by log absence.

UPDATE:
Found that the application crashes also on a simple ...doc().set() or ...doc().update() request.

Comment: Its may be because of memory optimisation. If your collection has so many data it will check every data. And it exceeds memory means OS will automatically terminate your app.

Comment: I've also tried on a collection with just only one document containing only one simple string field, but the result is the same.

Comment: Can you post some other code. Prior before performing this task. Because i once had the issue because we checked all contacts in our application to filter registered contacts in our case.

Comment: Not much code, i've even tried to call this line from the inistate of the main widget.
Also tried to put this just after the main firebase initialization.

Comment: UPDATE: Solved itself by updating to xCode 15.1